# Downloading external REST API responses to S3 where the endpoints are variable

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, rest

My project involves calling a 3rd party REST API and saving the response as JSON to be stored in an S3 bucket.

The data to be downloaded is accessed from:

```
myapi.com/data/{batch}/{id}
```

The response is around 1MB in size.

The JSON containing available id numbers for a batch can be accessed from:

```
myapi.com/data/{batch}/ids
```

The JSON containing available batch numbers can be accessed from:

```
myapi.com/data/batches
```

New ids typically become available on a weekly basis, and new batch numbers become available every month.

I've seen answers to questions about getting external REST API responses into s3 suggesting to create a scheduled Lambda function to call an id endpoint and push the JSON to an appropriately named S3 location. I'm struggling with 2 issues:

1. How do I provide the Lambda with the ids it should be calling, including ids that are newly available and omitting ids that have been previously downloaded?
2. How do I deal with bulk data? There are a lot of historical batches available which need to be downloaded as a one-off, and several new batches can become available at a time. Downloading these will exceed the 15 minute Lambda time limit.

Is the Lambda approach suitable? Are there any standard architectures for this kind of requirement that I can be referred to?

Answer (score 0):

You can look into [AWS Batch](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/batch/latest/userguide/what-is-batch.html).

You basically create a Docker image that runs the script you wrote and schedule the job to be run regularly using CloudWatch. Since AWS Batch does not have a time-limit if you use On-Demand instance and you can use larger instances if you need more memory/performance, it seems to be suitable to achieve your goal.